# pg_toast table not reduced in size after autovacuum

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

I'm on Postgresql 9.3.

**I have a monstrous pg_toast table, `pg_toast_675632`, taking up 27 GB.**

Unless I am misunderstanding, this `pg_toast_675632` is so large because I had a large `json` column in the data table that the `pg_toast_675632` is related to, `my_table`. So I massively simplified the json in `my_table` (i.e from json with 100 elements down to 2-5 elements). However, after autovacuum the `pg_toast_675632` is still 27 GB. Is this because autovacuum doesn't return reclaimed space to disk? [See the 3rd paragraph of 23.1.2 at this link.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/routine-vacuuming.html)

1. **So based on the documentation at the above link do I need to manually run `VACUUM (FULL) pg_toast_675632`?**

I know that `VACUUM (FULL)` takes a long time and will lock the `pg_toast_675632` from writes for the duration.

2. What are the risks of `VACUUM FULL pg_toast_675632`? Would this be equivalent to locking `my_table` since that's what `pg_toast-675632` is related to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct autovacuum won't reclaim space.

You'd have to run `VACUUM (FULL)` on `my_table`, that will also free the space in the TOAST table.

The downside is the `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock that will prevent all concurrent activity while `VACUUM (FULL)` runs.

As superuser you *can* run `VACUUM` on a TOAST table directly, but I don't see the advantage.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you for the explanation.